# Tangencial Velocity along a circle with angular acceleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-kinematics

Suppose a particle walks a circle's perimeter from $0$ to $\tfrac{\pi}{2}$. Its vertical velocity is $V_{1}$, constant. Its tangential speed increases as a function of theta and $V_{1}$.

[image]

Given $V_{1}$, r, what is the derivative of Theta with respect to time? I assume $V_{2} = \tfrac{V_{1}}{\cos\theta}$. Ultimately, I am trying to find the expression for the position of the particle along the path for any point in time.

Let me know if this question belongs elsewhere, or if I could be asking it better.

Answer (score 0):

If the vertical velocity is constant then work out the position of the particle at a time $t$ in the rest frame of the circular motion $(x(t),y(t))$.
Then add the change in the $y$ position due to the uniform translational motion $v_1$ $\Rightarrow (x(t),y(t)+v_1\cdot t)$

Comment: Thank you very much for the input, but I'm not able to follow it.

Comment: At first assume that V1 is zero and work out the accelerated motion along the circular path.

Comment: I really can't see how this helps. V1 is constant, so if it is zero it stays zero. Moreover, working out the accelerated motion along the circular path is what I'm trying to do in the first place, and can't. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As the particle moves on circle, $v_2=r\dot{\theta}$ ($\dot{\theta}=\frac d{dt}\theta$)

$v_2=\large{\frac{v_1}{\cos \theta}}=r\dot{\theta}\;\Longrightarrow\;\dot{\theta}=\large{\frac{v_1}{r\cos\theta}}$

$y=r\sin\theta=v_1t$ (because $v_1$ is constant)

$x=r\cos\theta=\sqrt{r^2-v_1^2t^2}$ , $0\le \theta\le \pi/2$

After $\theta=\pi/2$, the particle cannot move on the circle, as $v_1$ is constant.